# Pandas rolling.corr returns only erroneous values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, correlation

Hope someone here can help me, as I can't seem to crack what's the problem.

I have two series of data, for which I am trying to calculate a rolling correlation with a two-row window, using pandas [rolling correlation]https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.corr.html functionality, as follows `r_corr=series1.rolling(2).corr(series2)`

Example of Data:

```
2010-01-08         NaN
2010-01-15    0.070039
2010-01-22   -0.047273
2010-01-29    0.013359
2010-02-05    0.109228
                ...   
2017-11-17    0.034265
2017-11-24    0.024689
2017-12-01    0.009061
2017-12-08    0.041224
2017-12-15    0.000784
```

In return, I receive  a Series object filled with erroneous results:

```
2010-01-08    NaN
2010-01-15    NaN
2010-01-22    1.0
2010-01-29    1.0
2010-02-05    1.0
             ... 
2017-11-17    1.0
2017-11-24    1.0
2017-12-01    1.0
2017-12-08    1.0
2017-12-15    1.0
```

While NaN is to be expected because of the size of the window, there is NO WAY the correlation between these two series will be 1 or -1 almost at any point, let alone all.

This, of course, can be confirmed by playing around with the standard correlation functionality `correlation=series1.corr(series2)`.

I checked the code, I checked the environment and haven't found anything that would explain such unwarranted behaviour from the function.

I am running this on:
Windows 10
Jupyter notebook
Python 3.8 installed from Conda
Pandas 1.0.5 installed from Conda

Comment: You are calculating correlations between two two-element series, which is always 1. Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: change it to r_corr=series1.rolling(20).corr(series2) and cross check the data by hand for the last item in the list. (remember rho= cov(x,y)/(sigma x * sigma y) which is 1 for two items...)

Comment: @piterbarg, good spot!

Comment: @PaulBrennan you too. Thanks, both, so focused not he library, that completely forgot to sane check what on earth I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per suggestion from @PaulBrenan and @piterbag, the solution to the problem boils down to not having the correct window chosen for `r_corr=series1.rolling(20).corr(series2)` .

Once the window was corrected, so was the problem.